# How can I update a graph in a Dictionary with right key/value?

Tags: python, dictionary, graph

Hi all I have a graph in a dictionary and I would like to update the key/value in order to not skip "5" which is a node that has been previously removed, and so make 6 and 7 become 5 and 6 and so update also the value since this is a graph

```
{'1': ['2', '3', '6'], '3': ['1', '2', '4'], '2': ['3', '4'], '4': ['2', '3'], '7': ['6'], '6': ['1', '7']}
```

The output that I would like to aspect should be this:

```
{'1': ['2', '3', '5'], '3': ['1', '2', '4'], '2': ['3', '4'], '4': ['2', '3'], '6': ['5'], '5': ['1', '6']}
```

basically rescale everything with respect to the key/node that has been removed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's not working as expected?

Comment: @mackorone My code is not working otherwise I would have not asked there, to me question seems to be clear, I don't know how to improve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
mapping = {'6': '5', '7': '6'}
result = {}

for key, value in graph.items():
    val = [mapping.get(val, val) for val in value]
    k = mapping.get(key, key)
    result[k] = val
print(result)
```

Which gives:

```
{'1': ['2', '3', '5'], '3': ['1', '2', '4'], '2': ['3', '4'], '4': ['2', '3'], '6': ['5'], '5': ['1', '6']}
```

The equivalent one-liner is:

```
>>> result = {mapping.get(key, key): [mapping.get(v, v) for v in values]
              for key, values in graph.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be:

```
def get_ordered_dict(_dict):
    return dict(sorted(_dict.items()))

mydict = {'1': ['2', '3', '6'], '3': ['1', '2', '4'], '4': ['2', '3'], '7': ['6'], '2': ['3', '4'], '6': ['1', '7']}

mydict.update({'5': ['2', '3', '6']})

newdict = get_ordered_dict(mydict)

print(newdict)
```